# Template function declared as void - code doesn't work?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<int T, int U>
void foo(T a, U b)
{
    std::cout << a+b << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    foo(2,4);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

> error: variable or field 'foo' declared void
>
> error: expected ')' before 'a'
>
> error: expected ')' before 'b'
>
> In function 'int main()':
> error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope

Comment: That's not how templates work. Your template parameters are classes, or `typename`s, not `int`s.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What if I wanted to specify that both parameters will be `int`s? Obviously, I could just create a standard function, but can it be done using templates?

Comment: Since `T` is not a type, `foo` can't be function. Thus, it must be a variable, and `void` is not a valid type for a variable. (Note that `template<int T> int variable(T);` is a valid declaration in C++14.)

Comment: @grizloni97 If you want to specify that both parameters are `int`, you shouldn't use a template function.

Comment: @grizloni97 you can do that. But then you don't need to pass function parameters, only template parameters: `template <int T, int U> void foo() {...}` and call via: `foo<2,4>();`

Comment: @griz How exactly do you think that template function will differ from a standard function in that case?

Comment: If you want both parameters to be `int` you just declare an ordinary function with two int parameters. That's it. That's what ordinary functions are for. This is not what templates are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template parameters can be integers, for example:

```
template<int A, int B>
void bar()
{
    std::cout << A+B << std::endl;
}
```

However, it seems like you want to parametrize your method on the **types** of the parameters, not on integer **values**. The correct template would be this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void foo(T a, U b)
{
    std::cout << a+b << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    bar<2,4>();
    foo(2,4);     // note: template parameters can be deduced from the arguments
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know that the purpose of templates is genericness, but I was actually wondering what the syntax for passing two `int`s was, which is the first part of your answer.

Comment: @grizloni97 non-type parameters arent rare, but they arent the most common thing either. You can take a look at `std::array` for a nice example of a non-type parameter (the second parameter is the size of the array)

Answer (score 4):

Your `T` and `U` in your template are not types. You need to change it to:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void foo(T a, U b) {
}
```